# Need help installing Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl, cpan, parseexcel

I am trying to install Spreadsheet::ParseExcel to use with ExcelLatex. This is what I did:
Installed Active perl, Then install CPAN.pm by `perl -MCPAN -e shell` 
I was asked for configuration and mirror site and I let perl do the auoconfoguration. At the end I got the following message: `Autoconfiguration complete.`Then I tried:
`perl -MCPAN -e 'install "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel"'`
And it tried to install it but at the end I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/5.12/Spreadsheet'
mkdir /Library/Perl/5.12/Spreadsheet: Permission denied at     /System/Library/Perl/5.12/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 494

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
```

I really appreciate it one please help me how I can solve the problem

Comment: This may help: [How To Install Perl Modules](http://ubuntublog.org/install-perl-modules.htm)

Comment: Ok, so I tried Method 1 and 2 in this website: [link](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/docs/WriteExcel_Install.html) and both of them gave me the error I mentioned; then I posted a question here. Amazingly, the suggested solution worked! Here is the solution: after installing CPAN, try this:    `sudo su`    `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and finally    `install Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` and you are all set!

Comment: The "Permission denied" message you got suggested the need to `sudo su` for the install.  Am glad it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is trying to create a directory in the root (mkdir /Library/Perl/5.12/Spreadsheet)

You have to be root to be able to do that.

You may could use [PerlBrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) or [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm) to install your perl libs into your home dir.

```
  # Install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and its missing dependencies to the '~/perl5' directory
  perl -MCPAN -Mlocal::lib -e 'CPAN::install(Spreadsheet::WriteExcel)'

  # Just print out useful shell commands
  $ perl -Mlocal::lib
  export PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base /home/username/perl5'
  export PERL_MM_OPT='INSTALL_BASE=/home/username/perl5'
  export PERL5LIB='/home/username/perl5/lib/perl5/i386-linux:/home/username/perl5/lib/perl5'
  export PATH="/home/username/perl5/bin:$PATH"
  #create a environment setting script and execute it.
  perl -Mlocal::lib > ~/.setenv && . ~/.setenv
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot; I am not familiar with Perl and I guess this is the reason for facing all of these problems. Thanks again.